# How to get a line from one json file and another from a different json file using node.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, json

I am trying to combine lists of information from different .txt files.

Example:
(text1.txt):

```
type1
type2
type3
```

(text2.txt):

```
variable1
variable2
variable3
```

I want the program to give me something like this:
(I can set the separator character but I will use ':' for the example)

```
type1:variable1
type1:variable2
type1:variable3
type2:variable1
type2:variable2
type2:variable3
type3:variable1
type3:variable2
type3:variable3
```

Does anyone know how I would even start to go about that in node.js

I know I can create an array from each file using this:

```
var txt1Array = fs.readFileSync('./text1.txt').toString().split("\n");
var txt2Array = fs.readFileSync('./text2.txt').toString().split("\n");
```

But after that, I don't know how to set up a for loop to add all of the text2 files after each text1 file data pieces.

EDIT: if anyone doesn't know, fs.readFileSync is how im getting the data from the different text files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that for example ?

```
const txt1Array = fs.readFileSync('./text1.txt').toString().split("\n");
const txt2Array = fs.readFileSync('./text2.txt').toString().split("\n");

const resultArray = [];

for (let str1 of txt1Array) {
  for (let str2 of txt2Array) {
    resultArray.push(`${str1}:${str2}`);
  }
}
```

It seems too simple, maybe I didn't get right the question.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help... Could you explain what the code provided means, mainly the for loops...

Comment: You welcome! well if you don't understand this code you should probably learn basic algorithm stuff, there are probably a lot of very good courses on internet that you can follow. But basically the first loop is going throw all the elements of the first array and for each item we are going throw all the elements of the second array to put the string concatenation in the result array.

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation. It's not that I haven't learned it, I just don't see the `${str1}:${str2}` very much.

Comment: it's just ES6 string interpolation